# Showing percentage discount in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried this snippet: https://gist.github.com/vividvilla/7137659#file-sale-flash-php
to show % discount on sales badge in WooCommerce.

The problem is that for variations that do not have any discount, a badge of 0% is displayed. Can anyone guide me on how to avoid that.

Optionally, for variations I would like to show "Upto x%" instead of % dicount.

Answer (score 1):

At line 42, replace

```
    $percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    echo $price . sprintf( __('%s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' ); ?></div>
```

with

```
$percentage = round( ( ( $product->regular_price - $product->sale_price ) / $product->regular_price ) * 100 );
    if ( $percentage ) 
      echo $price . sprintf( __('%s', 'woocommerce' ), $percentage . '%' )
    else 
      echo $price;
```

?>

Looks like `$maximumper` is already showing the maximum discount percentage.

Are you just trying to change the words?

At line 32,change

```
echo $price . sprintf( __('Up to %s', 'woocommerce' ), $maximumper . '%' ); ?></div>
```